# How to calculate transformation using coordinates of rectangle?

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, geometry, transformation

Hello friends I am working on a project and I have a problem.
See Images below
[image]

This purple rectangle is my main region which I want to rotate and transform. I have rotated this using Qtransform rotate at 30 degrees and has size(180,173). I have calculated the cords of inner region and pass those to paint event and when I resize outer Rectangle this inner rectangle is drawn using painterpath see image below
[image]
Now this purple region in img 2 looks like transformed because I have drawn only cords when I reduced the size of outer rectacle.

So my question is, Is there any method to calculate at what angle inner region gets transformed If yes please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are able to get coordinates of target figure (after applying the transform). You can get the angle (in radiance) between a vector and the X axis using `atan2` function:

```
QPointF vector = vector_end - vector_start;
double angle = atan2(vector.y(), vector.x());
```

Difference of `angle` values of two vectors will give you angle between those two vectors. You may need to make sure that the difference is in [0, 2π] range by adding or substracting 2π.

Comment: Thanks for reply Pavel, I have a question is there any way that I can define my own transformation matrix according to points that I am drawing to create new shape,  after rotation I can easily get transformation matrix as I can get m11,m12... values of Qtransform, but after that I have calculated points after rotation of inner rect, now when I resize outer rect inner rect is drawn using paint event. If I reduce size of outer rect top and bottom of purple(inner) rect remains same and only left and right gets changes according to percentage. So is there any way from which I can get matrix?