# How to get transformation matrix using old transformation matrics and co-ordinates?

Tags: c++, qt, transform

Hello friends can any one clear me about what is w' in basic matrix operation formula in Qtransform below is code and what is difference between perspective and affine transform. Actually I am trying to find the at what values Img3 gets transformed?

```
x' = m11*x + m21*y + dx
y' = m22*y + m12*x + dy
if (is not affine) 
{
     w' = m13*x + m23*y + m33
     x' /= w'
     y' /= w'
```

}

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: In above matrix formula what is w'? Actually i am trying to calculate matrix from 8 cords you can see two images from my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671481/how-to-calculate-transformation-using-coordinates-of-rectangle I am trying to find transformation matrix of purple rect in Img2

Comment: calculate is a very vague word.

Comment: yes, the m11 etc. functions tell you the transformation matrix of your rectangle object.

Comment: so you want a function to tell you where the coords of inner should be after outer is resize?

Comment: but Img3 is drawn using cords and not by Qtransform function

Comment: no I want the function to calculate tranformation matrics when I have old transformation matrics i.e. of img2 and cords of inner rect, so that when I set any Image into inner rect that image should get all the properties of inner rect i.e. transforamtion

Comment: cords of purple rect in img2 are {QPointF(125.307, 0) QPointF(307, 157.85) QPointF(181.693, 302) QPointF(0, 144.15)} and m11...m33 are {0.75471, 0.656059, 0, -0.656059, 0.75471, 0, 92.3338, -55.9579, 1}.
now cords of purple rect in img3 are {QPointF(125.307, 0) QPointF(307, 49.1322) QPointF(181.693, 94) QPointF(0, 44.8678)} now I want to find the transformation matrix of purple rect in img3.

Answer (score 0):

w' is just a variable that they use to store the data obtained from `m13*x + m23*y + m33`
it is just a variable.

> Affine transformation is any transformation(e.g reflections, rotations, shears, translation etc.) that preserves
>   collinearity (i.e., all points lying on a line initially still lie on
>   a line after transformation) (Wolfram [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTransformation.html))

affine transformations are aslo refered to as affinities.

Perspective Transformations refers to the "transformation" from the 3d world projections into 2d image(screen).

//EDIT

`I am trying to find transformation matrix of purple rect in Img2`

This is the transformation matrix:

[image]

This is aslo transformation matrix:

[image: Image2]

```
QTransform::m11 (), 
QTransform::m12 (), 
QTransform::m13 (), 
QTransform::m21 (), 
QTransform::m22 (),
QTransform::m23 (),
QTransform::m31 (),
QTransform::m32 (),
QTransform::m33 ()
```

These functions give you the transformation matrix
It would help you more if you went to Math.SE because they do all the math stuff there...

Comment: Actually When I rotate purple rect in img1 I get transformation of that but after that when I resize outer rect, inner rect gets fit into outer I have manage it by calculating cords of inner rect when it get rotated, and then I am simply drawing it inside outer rect using painterpath and not using setting transform, but I want to find the transformation of purple rect in img2. Is there any way to find that?

Comment: do you want to angle of rotation?

Comment: transformation of purple rect from img1 to img2 is rotation.

Comment: Actually size of inner rect and outer rect are same at first, when I rotate inner rect then outer rect gets resize according to rotation of inner rect, Now when I resize outer rect then I simply draw the points using percentage of distance between points of outer and inner rect. Actually both get resize but inner gets fit into outer by setting cords and not transformedbut it looks like it gets transformed so I want to find that transformation matrix

Comment: can you post a picture of the outer and inner rect to see want you want?

Comment: I have edited the question please see that and explain me it is possible or not Thanks for responding